# loading Javascript referenced in a static web page via Twig

Tags: javascript, symfony, twig, symfony-2.1

I'm trying to convert a static web page to a Twig template format, such that older documentation can be displayed on a new Symfony app. However, this older page references JS files it requires to function that will not load.

I have converted the static HTML page to Twig format, as well as adding the directory of this static web page's files to the YML file for my app so Twig will recognize the filepath.

```
twig:
  \\other config stuff here
  paths:
    "%kernel.root_dir%/../src/AppBundle/ExampleBundle/Resources/static": Example
```

The page doesn't 404, but none of the JS or CSS components will load when Twig renders the page.

`testapp.com/_assets/components/prism-php.min.js net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)`

The directories and files all exist.

Comment: Does `testapp.com/_assets/components/prism-php.min.js` exists? This hasn't anything to do with Twig: Twig just generates HTML *on the server* and sents it to the browser. The browser will then just load the resources that are referenced in the HTML

Comment: How are you including the javacsript